# Feature of ExtractEditText and AppCompactEditText

Tags: android

What are the feature of ExtractEditText and AppCompactEditText? How it differ from EditText?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatEditText.html

Answer (score 0):

extractedText is a Specialization of EditText for showing and interacting with the extracted text in a full-screen input method.

AppCompatEditText is a EditText which supports compatible features on older version of the platform.

Both extractedText and AppCompatEditText are extended for EditText

You will get more details from the below links

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatEditText.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/ExtractEditText.html